# Using persistence.xml to create a Session to query the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I am familiar with using Hibernate and the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file to create a `Session`.

However, I have a `persistence.xml` file within my project, not the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

How do I use it to create a `Session` that I can then use to query my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `persistance.xml` you should use `EntityManager`. How to use `EntityManager` you can find in [Hibernate, JPA – Part 1](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/tutorial-hibernate-jpa-part-1.html) tutorial.

> The key config file for JPA is `persistence.xml`. This lives in the
>   `META-INF` directory. It details what the persistence driver to use
>   and what JNDI data source to connect to. Additional properties can
>   also be specified, in this case we’ll include some Hibernate
>   properties.

Next pat is about [Hibernate, JPA & Spring MVC – Part 2](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/tutorial-hibernate-jpa-spring-mvc-part.html).